# String match failing (Find if a word is present in a line)

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm trying to find if a string is present in a line.

```
for search_item in get_uniq_entities(fname):
    search_item_key = str(search_item)
    for line in open(data_path + '%s_tweets.csv' % fname):
        if "SJHD" in line:
            if search_item_key in line:
               # Do Something
```

The debug output of this code is as below. For some reason, although the search word "Martin" is present in the line, Python fails to match the line.

```
    line={str}'2020-06-19 04:02:09,b\'#Martin KJE is at 2.0\\n\\nRisk Warning: Mandatory check needed to confirm.\\nDisclaimer: NTH \\xe2\\x80\\xa6'
'
    search_item={str_}b'Martin
    search_item_key={str}'b\'Martin'
```

`search_item` was of type `{str_}` due to the use of `numpy` in the function that generates this value. I've typecasted it to string. Stillthe match doesn't happen.

Please could I request help to spot what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There's a `#` in the string which is not in the search string...

Comment: Thanks Nick. It shouldn't matter right because a substring can be any part of the main string/sentence yeah?

Comment: Yes, but `b\'Martin` can't match `b\'#Martin`

Comment: Appending a # at the beginning of the search string shows up as '#b\'Martin' & still doesn't match

Comment: Thanks NIck. Please post this as the answer & I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not really an answer, it's more pointing out an impossibility. I don't think it's worth an answer. As long as you're happy, I'm happy.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Appreciate your help mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved by Nick

There's a # in the string which is not in the search string... – Nick 15 hours ago